# I imported some html code from a JSON file in my react js project and web browsers display the html syntax as text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqxR0.png)My Json file contains UTF8 string.

```
 {
    "id": "014",
    "title": "The Tower / La Maison DIeu",
    "cover": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uenoeki54/Tarot-    Project/main/src/assets/cards/atuXIVthumb.jpg",
    "essay":  "\u003c\u0048\u0032\u0020\u0061\u006c\u0069\u0067\u006e\u003d\u0022\u0063\u0065\u006e\u0074\u0065\u0072\u0022\u0020\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u003d\u0022\u0063\u0069\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u006f\u006e\u0022\u0020\u003e\u003c\u0069\u003e\u0044\u0065\u0073\u0074\u0072\u0075\u0063\u0074\u0069\u0
```

I import it in my react js component.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import cards from '../assets/cards.json';

function Card() {
const { cardId } = useParams();
let card = cards.filter((cards) => cards.id === cardId);
console.log(card[0].id);
console.log(card[0].essay);

return (
   <div className="main">
     <img src={card[0].cover} className="main-illustration"></img>
     <div className="text">
       <h1>{card[0].title}</h1>
       {card[0].essay}
     </div>
   </div>
 );
```

Everythig works fine, but the string named "essay", which contains html, is not interpreted by web browsers as html...

I tried to enter my html code in different ways , but the only way for it to work is to encode it as UTF8. It works, but the browser doesn't seem to notice it's html.

Comment: That's the whole point, otherwise any bad actor could inject their own HTML through things like usernames, posts, whatever, and take over your page with XSS. You have to explicitly state you _really_ want this one thing as HTML, using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly answers my question !!